# Database builtin function calls in codeigniter where clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am executing a database query in my controller but it is showing 0 results. If I execute the query on the `phpMyAdmin` then it is showing results there but not in the web controller.
My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE DATE(orders.date) = DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

and in controller i am executing it like this:

```
$order_notification = $this->db- >where('DATE(orders.date)','DATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)')->get('orders')->result_array();
$total_notifications = count($order_notification);
```

Where orders is my database table.

Comment: Did you try to troubleshoot it with `print_r` and `die` commands ? What did it show in console ?

Comment: print the last query by using ```print_r($this->db->last_query());``` and check that same query is generated or not.

Comment: Probly your where sql is generated inside a single quote as string.
where DATE(orders.date)='DATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)'. Use normal $this->db->query();

Comment: A third parameter was needed to be passed into the where clause. Due to which codeigniter will not add backticks. I have posted the correct line of code in the answer. Thank you all for your responses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by passing 'FALSE' as my third parameter to prevent codeigniter from adding backticks.

```
$order_notification = $this->db->where('DATE(orders.date)','DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)',FALSE)->get('orders')->result_array();
```

Thank you everyone for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Another classic approach :

```
$total_notifications = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `orders` WHERE DATE(orders.date) = DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY)")->result_array();
```